# Problema ao pegar query params na URL pelo Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express.js

Estou criando uma rota `GET` que devolve um item de um array de usuários, porém não tenho retorno quando uso `req.query.id`.
Quando uso `req.params.id` da certo, mas nesse caso quero testar por *query string* mesmo.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const users = ['junyor', 'Antonio', 'joao'];

app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.query.id;
    return res.json(users[id]);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

O URL acessado foi `localhost:3000/users?id=1`.

A resposta do servidor:

> ```
> Cannot GET /users
> ```

Comment: pra usar `query`, nao basta apenas deixar a rota como `app.get('/users', () => {})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É preciso entender a diferença entre um parâmetro de rota e a *query string* da rota.

Note no seu código:

> ```js
> app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
>   // ...
> });
> ```

O caminho que você definiu no primeiro argumento de `get` explicita um *route param*, isto é, um parâmetro que deve fazer parte do caminho da requisição. Desse modo, se você fizer uma requisição para `/users?id=1`, esse *handler* de rota — que exige um parâmetro — não será executado.

Um parâmetro de rota é diferente de um "parâmetro" *query string*, veja:

#### Exemplos

- `/users/1`: `1` seria o parâmetro de rota `:id`.
- `/users/foo-bar`: `foo-bar` seria o parâmetro `:id`.

Note que `:id` não exige nenhum formato específico. Desde que seja válido em uma URL, ele será devidamente capturado.

Uma *query string*, por outro lado, pode ser anexada em qualquer rota.

- `/users/1?paramName=paramValue`: `1` seria o parâmetro de rota `:id` e `paramValue` seria o valor do parâmetro de *query string* `paramName`.

Assim, para acessar um parâmetro da *query string*, utilize [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query). Paralelamente, para acessar um parâmetro de rota, utilize [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params).

Então, seu código ficará assim:

```js
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  return res.json(users[id]);
});
```

Em suma, não faz sentido declarar o *route param* na URL da rota se você não pretende usá-lo, então, se você achar o formato de *query string param* mais válido no seu caso, pode fazer:

```js
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.query.id;
  return res.json(users[id]);
});
```

Note que, neste último caso, como o parâmetro `:id` (ou qualquer outro) não é exigido na URL, o *route handler* será executado normalmente.

Para saber mais, consulte a [documentação sobre roteamento do Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Comment: Perfeito, agora ficou claro. imaginei que sempre precisava declarar a variavel na rota, mas agora deu certo! vLw amigo.